# Heroku Port 5000 not connecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am doing a Saas course from edx.org,using ruby on rails.
The course needs to deploy my app running in virtual box  to heroku.
My host and guest machine are Ubutu 12.04
The problem is  , this command does not work .

heroku run rails db:migrate

Even tried with troubleshooting on Heroku site ,which points the same above issue

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/oneoff-admin-ps#troubleshooting

But even this command did not work

telnet rendezvous.runtime.heroku.com 5000

It is clear port issue , I am unable to breakthrough.

Any help ?

Answer (score 3):

If this is the error message:

```
$ heroku run console                           
Running `console` attached to terminal... up, run.2077
!
!    Error connecting to process
$
```

Try this: `heroku run:detached ls`

If it says:

```
Running `ls` detached... up, run.8825
Use `heroku logs -p run.8825` to view the output.
$ heroku logs -p run.8825                                                                                                 2013-04-11T21:30:50.137946+00:00 heroku[run.8825]: Starting process with command `ls`
2013-04-11T21:30:50.805694+00:00 app[run.8825]: app
2013-04-11T21:30:50.805694+00:00 app[run.8825]: bin
2013-04-11T21:30:50.805694+00:00 app[run.8825]: config
.
.
.
```

Then it's firewall-related but only because Heroku points the finger elsewhere.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos

This is a Heroku issue for many users because they are demanding a connection to port 5000.  In many enterprise environments where only ports 443/80/22 are usable, this leaves a large fraction of customers with lots of money out in the cold.  Heroku should take ownership and just help users make it work.  There is no technical reason they can't, and any argument as such would be to justify laziness.

Hackarounds like https://github.com/nzoschke/SSHeroku and charging for Proximo are non-starters, requiring more even more work diffused upon users and aren't scalable.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku development servers appear to be down right now for me. Type the following code in the command line to output your log:

```
heroku logs
```

Right now I am getting error code h99 which they say on their website:

> This indicates an internal error in the Heroku platform. Unlike all of the other errors which will require action from you to correct, this one does not require action from you. Try again in a minute, or check the status site.

The status site (status.heroku.com) says everything is okay... but my logs indicate there is something wrong on their end.

What does heroku logs output for you?